# Asp.Net MVC - Open HTML Controls

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, controls

I'm new to asp.net mvc. I'm looking to create some control for reusing html. I have a complex HTML box for example:

```
<div class="Box">
    <div class="Top"></div>
    <div class="Content">
        <div style="padding:10px;">
        [CONTENT GOES HERE]
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Previously using webforms I've been able to reuse this by inheriting from WebControl and override Render. But how can I implement this in MVC?

The Content of the box could of course be what ever. Other boxes for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest yet: using a UserControl

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
<div class="Box">
    <div class="Top"></div>
    <div class="Content">
        <div style="padding:10px;">
        <%= Model.Content %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Bottom"></div>
</div>
```

And then calling the user control with

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("NiceBox", New with {.Content = "The real content goes here"})%>
```

Comment: Is this method useful if let's say I want to put an entire form inside the box? I'm entirely clear about the "with {.Content..." part.

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. This approach is more useful to structured content. You can still use WebControls in MVC as long as they do not rely on `PostBack` or `ViewState`

Comment: So I can implement a webcontrol into a view in the same way as in a weboform? <prefix:name runat="server">stuff goes here</prefix:name> ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of one way to build it as an HtmlHelper extension method:

```
    public static string Box(this HtmlHelper helper, string content)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<div class=\"Box\" .......... );

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
        {
            builder.Append(content)
        }

        return builder.ToString();    
    }
```

In your view:

```
  <%= Html.Box(contentString) %>
```

Your other options are to create it as a partial view (.ascx) and pass it a ViewModel class that contained the content that you wanted to render.  Judging by the requirement of "the content could be anything", an HtmlHelper extension might be more flexible for you.